# Question on the proof step in the theorem 1 of the Gap statistic paper

Tags: clustering, expected-value, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, integral

From the Gap statistic [paper](https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/gap.pdf), during the proof for the theorem 1, we can see the below equality (p. 422),

$\begin{aligned} \operatorname{var}(X) & =\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(y-x)^2 f(x) f(y) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{~d} y \\ & =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \int_0^1\left\{F^{-1}(v)-F^{-1}(u)\right\}^2 \mathrm{~d} u \mathrm{~d} v \\ & =\int_0^1 \int_u^1\left\{\int_u^v \frac{1}{f\left\{F^{-1}(t)\right\}} \mathrm{d} t\right\}^2 \mathrm{~d} u \mathrm{~d} v\end{aligned}$

where $F$ and $f$ are unform CDF and PDF, respectively.

As I struggled, lower bound in the 3rd line $u$ shuold be $ u= \frac{1}{2}$ to prove the equality between 2nd and 3rd lines.

Do I think wrong?

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: I think the loss of the 1/2 comes with the change in the integral limits. The second line integrates over all $u$, $v$, and the third line only over $v\geq u$ -- that's the appeal to "symmetry" in the line below these equations in the paper

Comment: @Thomas Lumley Thank you for the crucial advice, now I can proceed with this paper more. By the way, the lower limit in the third line should be corrected as $u=0$?

Comment: Also, the symmetry can hold because it is the squared form.